# Database per tenant - a step by step example to confirm my thinking

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I just need confirmation I'm on the right track with this aspect I'm trying to implement.

**Step 1**: for each tenant create a new context eg

```
public class TenantOneContext : AbpZeroDbContext<Tenant, Role, User, TenantOneContext{


  public DbSet<MyModel1> MyModel1S { get; set; }
  public DbSet<MyModel1> MyModel2S { get; set; }
```

**Step 2**: 
I assume using a naming convention, that each context that exists, there is an associated [contextname]Configurer eg

```
public static class TenantOneContextConfigurer
    {
        public static void Configure(DbContextOptionsBuilder<TenantOneContext> builder, string connectionString)
        {
            builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        }

        public static void Configure(DbContextOptionsBuilder<TenantOneContext> builder, DbConnection connection)
        {
            builder.UseSqlServer(connection);
        }
```

**Step 3**: create new [contextname]Factory for each tenant-context eg

```
 public class TenantOneContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<TenantOneContext>
```

In the module that inherits `AbpModule` - add some code to do custom connection string resolving eg

```
public class MyAppEntityFrameworkModule : AbpModule { 

  //new code to  resolve conn strings / tennant
   Configuration.ReplaceService<IConnectionStringResolver, DbPerTenantConnectionStringResolver>(DependencyLifeStyle.Transient);
```

I think that is it - but looking for confirmation...:-)

Comment: Thanks for putting me straight - incredibly simple to achieve this with almost no coding - .  Testament to the frameworks excellent design

Comment: You're welcome! Posted it as an answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably don't need a different `DbContext` for each tenant, just a different connection.

> if so, is there a naming convention for mapping the conn strings ? or where does the mapping take place?

The connection string is stored in [Tenant](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/9ff01eb5e23820700e9455f3432bd61a97b484b4/src/Abp.Zero.Common/MultiTenancy/AbpTenantBase.cs#L62) entity:

```cs
public const int MaxConnectionStringLength = 1024;

[StringLength(MaxConnectionStringLength)]
public virtual string ConnectionString { get; set; }
```

The mapping takes places in [DbPerTenantConnectionStringResolver](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/dev/src/Abp.ZeroCore.EntityFrameworkCore/Zero/EntityFrameworkCore/DbPerTenantConnectionStringResolver.cs#L50-L63):

```cs
if (args.TenantId == null)
{
    // Requested for host
    return base.GetNameOrConnectionString(args);
}

var tenantCacheItem = _tenantCache.Get(args.TenantId.Value);
if (tenantCacheItem.ConnectionString.IsNullOrEmpty())
{
    // Tenant has no dedicated database
    return base.GetNameOrConnectionString(args);
}

return tenantCacheItem.ConnectionString;
```