# How to change the configuration to build as single deployment with multi-database?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I came a cross this boilerplate just couple of weeks ago and it's the coincidence that I was working on designing Multi-tenant Saas Architecture using .Net Core Framework, EFCore as ORM, SPA(Angular)as presentation layer, and OData Api but then I found this boilerplate is exactly what I am looking for. I have one question how to set-up configuration on this sample Event Saas app to make it as Single Deployment with multi-database?

I have noted there is appsetting.json where subdomains are stored and in each entity for example Event is inherited from IMustHaveTenant that means each entity should have TenantId means this setup is suitable for single deployment with single database (database filter is automatically applied by aspboilerplate)  but I am looking to make it single deployment with multiple database (Each database per tenant). It will be great if you just give me some clues.

Note: [This](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Multi-Tenancy#single-deployment-multiple-database) is what I am talking about.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Database per tenant - a step by step example to confirm my thinking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47349344/database-per-tenant-a-step-by-step-example-to-confirm-my-thinking)